# A book about 2 girls who find a magic glove

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

This is a short chapter book about 2 girls who find a magic glove in a box of old things. It allows them to draw like an artist and play the piano beautifully.

Comment: This is very brief is there anything else about it that you remember that you could [edit] in? For example, when did you read this?

Answer (score 9):

**What the Witch Left** (1973) by **Ruth Chew**

There's a [summary](http://ruthchew.com/about-the-books/What-the-Witch-Left.htm) on a (fan?) website devoted to her. Here's a relevant bit from the summary:

> Katy and Louise find some things locked in a dresser: a bathrobe, gloves, boots, a mirror, and a metal box. The gloves seem to make Katy play the piano, do homework, sew, and draw much better than usual.